# How to insert the search query string in an anchor

Tags: php, search

Let's take 3 keywords: **sunlight**, **mirror**, **eclipse**

When doing a search using a form:

```
<form method="get" action="search.php">
    <input name="q" type="search">
</form>
```

the url looks very nice, like this:

```
http://localhost/gallery/search.php?q=sunlight+mirror+eclipse
```

So far so good.

When trying to insert the search query string in an anchor, like this

```
// get the query string
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $current_q = $_GET['q'];
}

<a href="<?php echo 'http://localhost/gallery/search.php?q=' . $current_q; ?>">this is my query</a>
```

i get something ugly with weirds characters in between keywords, like this:

```
http://localhost/gallery/search.php?q=sunlight%20mirror%20eclipse
```

Why? And how to make it nice, like when using a form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` this will get anything after `?`
this will get it in the same way the URL is getting it

```
 http://localhost/gallery/search.php?q=sunlight+mirror+eclipse
```

some code

```
 <?php
 $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 $query = str_replace(' ', '+', urldecode($query));    
 echo "<a href='http://localhost/gallery/search.php?$query'>this is my query</a>";
```

[Documentation PHP SERVER MANUAL](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: tried it but i get the weird characters in between keywords. By the way, i didnt down vote.